# grunt-contrib-cssmin: css source map appears empty in dev tools

Tags: json, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-cssmin

I am using grunt with `cssmin` to minify and concatenate css files.
Css files are well concatenated and minified but when I try to watch the non minified files in chrome dev tools under '`Sources`' tab, files appears empty.
Here is my `cssmin` task:

```
cssmin: {
    options: {
        report: 'gzip',
        keepSpecialComments: 0,
        sourceMap: true,
        outputSourceFiles: true
    },
    target: {
        files: {
            'web/assets/dist/css/vendors.min.css': [
                'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
                'bower_components/chosen/chosen.min.css',
                'bower_components/slabText/css/slabtext.css',
                'bower_components/video.js/dist/video-js.css',
                'bower_components/video.js/dist/video-js.css'
            ],
            'web/assets/dist/css/app.min.css': [
                'app/Resources/assets/css/jumbotron-narrow.css',
                'app/Resources/assets/css/custom.css',
            ],
        }
    }
},
```

Source map setting is enabled under chrome.
`web/assets/dist/css/app.min.css.map` looks like this:

```
{
    "version":3,
    "sources":["app/Resources/assets/css/jumbotron-narrow.css","app/Resources/assets/css/custom.css"],
    "names":[],
    "mappings":"AAeA,QAdA,KAeI,eAAgB,KADpB,QA6BA,WAEI,cAAe,IAAI,MAAM,QA7C7B,KACI,YAAa,KCUb,YAAa,eAAkB,WDHnC,QAFA,QACA,WAEI,cAAe,KACf,aAAc,KASlB,WACI,WAAY,EACZ,cAAe,EACf,YAAa,KAIjB,QACI,YAAa,KACb,MAAO,KACP,WAAY,IAAI,MAAM,QAI1B,yBACI,WACI,UAAW,OAGnB,qBACI,OAAQ,KAAK,EAIjB,WACI,WAAY,OAGhB,gBACI,QAAS,KAAK,KACd,UAAW,KAIf,WACI,OAAQ,KAAK,EAEjB,gBACI,WAAY,KAIhB,oCAII,QAFA,QACA,WAEI,cAAe,EACf,aAAc,EAGlB,QACI,cAAe,KAGnB,WACI,cAAe,GC3EvB,WACI,YAAa,eACb,IAAK,iCAAkC,mBAG3C,WACI,YAAa,YACb,IAAK,8BAA+B,mBAOxC,GACI,WAAY,KACZ,eAAgB,UAChB,YAAa,EACb,YAAa,YAAe,WAC5B,YAAa,EAAI,EAAI,IAAI,KAG7B,4BACI,QAAS,MACT,YAAa,KACb,aAAc,KACd,cAAe,IAGnB,UACI,UAAW,MACX,WAAY,KAIhB,oBACI,MAAO,IAGX,sBACI,gBAAiB,KACjB,YAAa,EAGjB,cACI,aAAc,QAIlB,iCACI,QAAS"
 }
```

Version from my package.json:

```
 "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.12.0",
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Firstly, try specifying a `root` in your `options` of the `Gruntfile.js` as follows:

```js
// ...
cssmin: {
  options: {
    // ...
    root: 'web/assets/dist/css/' // <-- Add this too.
  },
  target: {
    // ...
  }
  /...
```

---

#### The Issue

The *sourceMap* file that `grunt-contrib-cssmin` is generating is incorrectly specifying the paths in the `sources` Array. The resultant *sourceMap* should be as follows:

**app.min.css.map**

```json
{
  "version":3,
  "sources":[
    "../../../../app/Resources/assets/css/jumbotron-narrow.css",
    "../../../../app/Resources/assets/css/custom.css"
  ],
  "names":[],
  "mappings":"AAeA,QAdA,KAeI,eAAgB,KADpB,QA6BA,WAEI,cAAe,IAAI,MAAM,QA7C7B,KACI,YAAa,KCUb,YAAa,eAAkB,WDHnC,QAFA,QACA,WAEI,cAAe,KACf,aAAc,KASlB,WACI,WAAY,EACZ,cAAe,EACf,YAAa,KAIjB,QACI,YAAa,KACb,MAAO,KACP,WAAY,IAAI,MAAM,QAI1B,yBACI,WACI,UAAW,OAGnB,qBACI,OAAQ,KAAK,EAIjB,WACI,WAAY,OAGhB,gBACI,QAAS,KAAK,KACd,UAAW,KAIf,WACI,OAAQ,KAAK,EAEjB,gBACI,WAAY,KAIhB,oCAII,QAFA,QACA,WAEI,cAAe,EACf,aAAc,EAGlB,QACI,cAAe,KAGnB,WACI,cAAe,GC3EvB,WACI,YAAa,eACb,IAAK,iCAAkC,mBAG3C,WACI,YAAa,YACb,IAAK,8BAA+B,mBAOxC,GACI,WAAY,KACZ,eAAgB,UAChB,YAAa,EACb,YAAa,YAAe,WAC5B,YAAa,EAAI,EAAI,IAAI,KAG7B,4BACI,QAAS,MACT,YAAa,KACb,aAAc,KACd,cAAe,IAGnB,UACI,UAAW,MACX,WAAY,KAIhB,oBACI,MAAO,IAGX,sBACI,gBAAiB,KACjB,YAAa,EAGjB,cACI,aAAc,QAIlB,iCACI,QAAS"
}
```

Note the *sourceRoot* prefixes `../../../../` added to each path in the `sources` Array.

In the [SourceMap Specification](https://sourcemaps.info/spec.html#h.75yo6yoyk7x5) a section reads:

> **Resolving Sources**
>
> If the sources are not absolute URLs after prepending of the “sourceRoot”, the sources are resolved relative to the SourceMap (like resolving script src in a html document).

If specifying a `root` path, *(as initially mentioned)*, does not resolve the issue then it indicates that this part of the specification is not being honoured by `grunt-contrib-cssmin`.

---

#### Alternate Solution

If the initial suggested fix does not work then consider adding a custom [Task](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#creating-tasks) to invoke a Function which fixes each `sources` path after the *sourceMap(s)* have been created by `grunt-contrib-cssmin`.

You could do something like this:

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig( {
    cssmin: {
      options: {
        report: 'gzip',
        keepSpecialComments: 0,
        sourceMap: true,
        outputSourceFiles: true
      },
      target: {
        files: {
          'web/assets/dist/css/vendors.min.css': [
            'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
            'bower_components/chosen/chosen.min.css',
            'bower_components/slabText/css/slabtext.css',
            'bower_components/video.js/dist/video-js.css'
          ],
          'web/assets/dist/css/app.min.css': [
            'app/Resources/assets/css/jumbotron-narrow.css',
            'app/Resources/assets/css/custom.css'
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  });

  /**
   * Helper function prefixes sources paths in sourceMap files with a sourceRoot.
   *
   * `grunt-contrib-cssmin` does not apply the correct sourceRoot for each
   * path in the `sources` Array. See github issue #248 for further info:
   * (https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin/issues/248)
   * 
   * @param {String} filePath - The path to the sourceMap to fix.
   * @param {String} sourceRootPrefix - The sourceRoot prefix e.g. ../../
   */
  function prefixSourceMap(filePath, sourceRootPrefix) {
    var json = grunt.file.readJSON(filePath);
    json.sources = json.sources.map(function (_path) {
      return sourceRootPrefix + _path;
    });
    grunt.file.write(filePath, JSON.stringify(json));
  }

  // Register Task to invoke function for fixing paths in each sourceMap file.
  grunt.registerTask('fixSourceMaps', 'Fix paths in each sourceMap', function () {
    prefixSourceMap('web/assets/dist/css/vendors.min.css.map', '../../../../');
    prefixSourceMap('web/assets/dist/css/app.min.css.map', '../../../../');
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');

  grunt.registerTask("default", [
    'cssmin',
    'fixSourceMaps' // <-- Must be after cssmin tasks.
  ]);
};
```

**Notes**

1. The the custom [grunt.registertask](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.registertask) named `fixSourceMaps` invokes the `prefixSourceMap` function for each *sourceMap* file to fix.
2. Two arguments are passed to the `prefixSourceMap` function, namely:

   - `filePath` - The path to the sourceMap to fix.
   - `sourceRootPrefix` - The sourceRoot prefix e.g. `../../`
3. For fixing both *sourceMap* files (`vendors.min.css.map` and `app.min.css.map`) the `sourceRootPrefix` argument is specified as `../../../../` - This is specified as four levels due to the relationship between the resultant `.min.css` file and it's location to the original *unminified* source `.css` file within your directory structure.

If you were to add another set of `.css` files to minify to your `cssmin.target.files` Task, in which the relationship between the resultant `.min.css` file and the *unminified* source `.css` file was not four levels, you will need to specify a different `sourceRootPrefix` value.

For example, lets say in `cssmin.target.files` the following css is to be minified:

```js
// ...
target: {
  files: {
    //...
    'web/assets/quux.min.css': [ // <-- Two levels deep
      'path/to/file/foo.css',
      'path/to/file/baz.css'
    ],
    // ...
  }
}
// ...
```

As the resultant `quux.min.css` is saved in the directory two levels deep then the `sourceRootPrefix` argument is passed to the `prefixSoureMap` functions as `'../../'`. For example:

```js
//...
grunt.registerTask('fixSourceMaps', 'Fix paths in each sourceMap', function () {
  prefixSourceMap('web/assets/quux.min.css.map', '../../');
  //...
});
//...
```

Comment: `root: 'web/assets/dist/css/'` does the trick! There was another mistake: original assets must be accessible by the webserver which wasn't the case in my configuration. My apache web root is web, so I move my original assets under this location and that's now ok.

Answer (score 0):

as explained in comment above, there was 2 issues in my Gruntfile :

- missing `root` directive as explained by @RobC
- original assets were not accessible by the webserver, so I moved them in a location under the web root  of my virtualhost. In my case `web/assets`. Here is my `cssmin` task that is now working:

  ```
  cssmin: {
      options: {
          root: 'web/assets/dist/css/',
          report: 'gzip',
          keepSpecialComments: 0,
          sourceMap: true,
          outputSourceFiles: true
      },
      target: {
          files: {
              'web/assets/dist/css/app.min.css': [
                  'web/assets/css/jumbotron-narrow.css',
                  'web/assets/css/custom.css',
              ],
          }
      }
  },
  ```